# How to change the fill color of a table in MS Word using delphi

Tags: delphi, ms-word

i use the code below to create and a word document, and add a table with information.
How can i change the fill color to white, background 1, darker 25% with delphi ole automation.

also, How can i change the font name to times new roman,
and the spacing before and after.

I tried `wrdDoc.Tables.Item(1).Cell(1,1).Range.pagelayout.Paragraphs.spacing.before:=2.9;` but it does not work, says the methot pagelayout is not supported.

I am using delphi xe3 and office 2013.

```
  WrdApp := CreateOLEObject('Word.Application');
  wrdDoc := wrdApp.Documents.Add();
  wrdDoc.Select;
  Wrddoc.SaveAs(ExtractFilePath(application.ExeName)+'Documents\temp.doc');

  wrdSelection := wrdApp.Selection;
  wrdDoc.Tables.Add(wrdSelection.Range,1,1);
  wrdDoc.Tables.Item(1).Columns.Item(1).SetWidth(300,wdAdjustNone);
  wrdDoc.Tables.Item(1).Borders.Item(wdBorderLeft).LineStyle:=wdLineStyleSingle;
  wrdDoc.Tables.Item(1).Borders.Item(wdBorderRight).LineStyle:=wdLineStyleSingle;
  wrdDoc.Tables.Item(1).Borders.Item(wdBorderTop).LineStyle:=wdLineStyleSingle;
  wrdDoc.Tables.Item(1).Borders.Item(wdBorderBottom).LineStyle:=wdLineStyleSingle;
  wrdDoc.Tables.Item(1).Cell(1,1).Range.Paragraphs.Alignment := wdAlignParagraphcenter;
  wrdDoc.Tables.Item(1).Cell(1,1).Range.InsertAfter(text);
```

Thank you very much

Comment: What would you expect `pagelayout` to do in terms of table markup?

Comment: Honestly, i was just taking a guess, i was hoping i would be able to change the line spacing before and after for the table...@GolezTrol

Comment: Font: `wrdDoc.Tables.Item(1).Rows.Item(i).Range.Font.Name := 'Times New Roman';`  Fill Colour: `wrdDoc.Tables.Item(1).Rows.Item(i).Cells.Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex:=  wcGray25;` -where i = rownumber.  Colours maybe limited to: `TWordColor = (wcAuto, wcBlack, wcBlue, wcTurquoise, wcBrightGreen, wcPink, wcRed, wcYellow, wcWhite, wcDarkBlue, wcTeal, wcGreen, wcViolet, wcDarkRed, wcDarkYellow, wcGray50, wcGray25);` 
Line Spacing: Not sure but ??WrdDoc.Selection.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacing